# Hamming code Ham(2,11) fixing transposition of letters

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let's say I am using the $Ham(2,11)$ code - the hamming code for which r = 2 and q=11 (length of alphabet). Can I detect errors caused by the transposition of 2 letters? If not, why?

Comment: Even though I've seen quite a variance of coding theoretical notation I don't recall ever seeing a code referred to as Ham(2,11). Can you please add a description of it?

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: Sounds like you mean the code with alphabet size $q=11$, length $n=(q^r-1)/(q-1)=12$ and dimension $k=n-r=10$. I was a bit surprised to see $r$ and $q$ as parameters, but it is clear now. Like with all Hamming codes, its minimum distance is three. So if two (distinct) letters accidentally trade places, the word you get is at Hamming distance two from a legal codeword. Therefore _____

Comment: Could you please expand further?